# Printing XRLabel on every Report Page

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

I have a method which get a XtraReport as Parameter. It should printing an infoarea on all Pages the Report got. How can i achieve this goal? It must be printed on DetailBand and the LabelText got Angle so i cant use PageInfo Control.

In fact the Problem is: How can i print a XRLabel on all ReportPages of a XtraReport Object.
I tried this out but without success:

```
XRLabel druckinfo = new XRLabel();
druckinfo.Angle = 90F;
druckinfo.Padding = new PaddingInfo(2, 2, 0, 0, 96F);
druckinfo.SizeF = new SizeF(29.16666F, 500F);
druckinfo.Font = new Font(StyleVerwaltung.Instance.Schriftart,
    StyleVerwaltung.Instance.SchriftgroesseDruckInfo);
druckinfo.Text = text;
druckinfo.LocationF = new PointF(0F, 500F);

foreach (Band band in _Report.Bands)
{
    if (band is DetailBand)
    {
        band.Controls.Add(druckinfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: is the `xrlabel` in the `Page Header` of your Report object? If you place it there it will printed on every page.

Comment: @MilenPavlov No the problem is that my company want it on DetailBand. The PageHeader and Footer got other information. But thanks for tip.

Comment: Can you add the label form the designer to your report and utilize `Before Print` event for this label?

Comment: @MilenPavlov Iam not able to use designer, because the method get the XtraReport in Parameter. I dont know the look and controls of the report. Just want to decorate it with one more label on every page. Seems to be difficult :-( Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DevExpress Support show me a way to solve my problem:

```
Image img = new Bitmap(300, 300);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);
Font schriftart = new Font(StyleVerwaltung.Instance.Schriftart,
    StyleVerwaltung.Instance.SchriftgroesseDruckInfo);
StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

_Report.Watermark.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomLeft;
_Report.Watermark.ImageViewMode = ImageViewMode.Clip;
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

g.TranslateTransform(0, g.VisibleClipBounds.Size.Height);
g.RotateTransform(270f);
g.DrawString(text, schriftart, Brushes.Black,
    new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)g.VisibleClipBounds.Size.Width,
                        (int)g.VisibleClipBounds.Height),
    format);
g.ResetTransform();
g.Flush();

_Report.Watermark.Image = img;
_Report.Watermark.ShowBehind = true;
```

It uses the Watermark to accomplish this task. It just works if you dont use Watermark in other context but for my goal it works as expected.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes i have written a Initialize Method which a call after the report is created. Then i can call ShowPreview.